# Azure Portal uses the active directory instance from my school

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal

I am currently logged in to the Azure Portal using a trial subscriptions (free 170 euro credit). I logged in with my Microsoft account from school. I took a trial subscription because I am interested in some services like Azure datalake gen2 and Azure databricks.

I am currently making a test project using this tutorial [Tutorial: Access Data Lake Storage Gen2 data with Azure Databricks using Spark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-use-databricks-spark). To complete this tutorial you need a tenant ID, application ID, and authentication key. The tenant ID is retrieved from the tab 'Azure Active Directory' in the Azure portal.

I am trying to retrieve the tenant ID (also refered to as the Directory ID) from Azure Active Directory. Unfortunately I am unable to retrieve this id because of the following problem.
*When clicking the tab 'Azure Active Directory' the following message is displayed: "You do not have access".*

Somehow Azure is automatically using the active directory instace from my school. In this AD instance I am a user. I don't need to access any information from the AD from my school. Is there anyway that I can tell Azure to create a new active directory instance for this account so I will have admin privileges? Or do I need to register again with a different account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new Azure Active Directory tenant from Azure Portal. Then make sure your subscription admin account can access that tenant. Then you can go to the subscription settings and change the AAD tenant it is linked to.